# Huffman minimum variance coding

Tags: probability, statistics, coding-theory

it is well known that Huffman code with minimum variance is preferable.
I've digged through entire Polish/English internet and this is what I found:
to build Huffman code with minimum variance you need to break ties with one of the following methods (of course probability of node is the most important):

- Select node that represents shortest tree
- Select node that was created earliest (consider leafs as created at start).

the problem is, that I couldn't find any proof of correctness of any of these methods.
Can someone proof any of these?

I will gladly clarify anything.

Comment: Does proof-by-experience count as a proof?

Comment: Nope. I need a legit proof.